# How to replace file content between some specific strings in java?

Tags: java

I have two files, want to put content of one file into another between some specific start string and end string.

> File_1
>
> > The first file content. Want to replace ***all the content here*** with the contents of second file.
>
> File_2
>
> > The Second file content.
>
> Required_File
>
> > The first file content. The Second file content. with the contents of second file.

**Assumptions made:**
start string and end string will be always unique

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to do:

1. Load the file into a String
2. With your String, find the start and end text. You can use regex or String.indexOf for this
3. Use String.replace to replace the middle content with the content you want
4. Write the String back to the file

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this quick mockup to give you an idea:

In my demo I wrote, 1.txt contains "My name is Andre.", and 2.txt contains "John". My code uses the two variables, `uniqueStart` and `uniqueEnd`, and uses the `indexOf` function of Strings to substring the parts we want of `1.txt`. It then puts the contents of `2.txt`, which is "John", in the middle, creating the final String `My name is John.`

I then save it to a new file just as a demonstration.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;


class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    String firstFileContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("1.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    String secondFileContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("2.txt")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    //First file content example: "My name is Andre."
    //Second file content example: "John".
    String uniqueStart = "My name is ";
    String uniqueEnd = ".";

    String combined = firstFileContent.substring(0, firstFileContent.indexOf(uniqueStart)+uniqueStart.length()) + secondFileContent + firstFileContent.substring(firstFileContent.indexOf(uniqueEnd), firstFileContent.length());
    //Combined = My name is John.

    Files.write(Paths.get("NewContent.txt"), combined.getBytes());
  }
}
```